# Writing to log file in java is tracked by file name or by something else (like inode, file handle, etc)?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, logback, logrotate

I use `logback` as well as `log4j2` in my java web apps for logging. So far, I've setup log rotation (and purging) from within logback and log4j2 but now I intend to use `logrotate` at an infrastructure level since there are lots of services (in other languages as well) and it's relatively easier to maintain one common way of handling log files.

While doing a POC, I setup the java app to write logs to a file `application.log` and also setup logrotate with a size criteria (of 1 MB). As expected, when the file size reached 1 MB, the log file was rotated by way of moving it to another file named `application.log.1`. At this point, I expected the java app to continue writing new logs to `application.log` file. However, the logs kept getting written in the rotated file i.e. `application.log.1`.

This makes me wonder whether the component within logback/log4j2 that writes the log content in the file tracks the file by its name or something else like an inode number or a file handler. Since the original active log file was not deleted but just moved with a new name.

I'm aware of the `copytruncate` option in logrotate which creates a copy of the active log file and then truncates the active log file, but I don't want to use this as this can lead to loss of log events for agents running on the machines which pushes the logs to systems like Elasticsearch and CloudWatch. Since truncate can happen before the agents have processed all the log entries.

How can I get the logging component to always write logs to a file named `application.log` even after the original file underneath gets moved?

Answer (score 0):

The logging framework opens the file for write and leaves the OutputStream open until the application ends or the file is rolled over or similar. On a Unix system you can move the file, rename it, or delete it but the application will keep writing to it. The application has no way of knowing the file was externally manipulated.

If you are using Log4j 2 you should use the RollingFileAppender and use the DeleteAction to delete old files.